# Polymer 2.0: polymer 1.0 hybrid elements not working in polymer 2.0?

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-starter-kit

New to polymer 2.0!
Polymer 1.0 elements don't work correctly with polymer 2.0.
What to do?
Can someone please provide a link for polymer 2.0 starter kit which also has new polymer 2.0 compatible elements.
So that i can setup a new project for polymer 2.0 from scratch and work without any hassle.
I have bower installed, so bower code for setting new polymer 2.0 project is welcome.
thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, is it so hard to type upgrade guide polymer into google search bar ? of course Polymer 1.x elements won't work in 2.0 because there is completely new syntax and different way of creating elements, styling them and so on.

You can see all changes here: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade

If your project isn't big or you just trying to play with polymer it's better to start from scratch. use official Polymer documentation but switch to Polymer 2.0

[image]

Comment: thank you!
actually i'm new to polymer and haven't used polymer 1.0, srry for the lame question!